# How to draw Stacked bar chart based on magnitude (in R plot ot ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

To clearly explain what I want to draw, I am giving a sample R code.
This is my matrix of data.

```
mat.all=matrix(c(1,rep(2,4),rep(3,6),rep(4,4),5,139.17365,136.27613,139.01464,135.47032,98.02343,136.28064,132.31289,135.26496,96.62991, 97.49587,90.17913,132.25711,96.01838,88.87682,89.06218,87.65776),16,2,byrow=F)
```

This gives

```
     [,1]      [,2]
 [1,]    1 139.17365
 [2,]    2 136.27613
 [3,]    2 139.01464
 [4,]    2 135.47032
 [5,]    2  98.02343
 [6,]    3 136.28064
 [7,]    3 132.31289
 [8,]    3 135.26496
 [9,]    3  96.62991
[10,]    3  97.49587
[11,]    3  90.17913
[12,]    4 132.25711
[13,]    4  96.01838
[14,]    4  88.87682
[15,]    4  89.06218
[16,]    5  87.65776
```

Here I need to draw 4 vertical bars each with height `mat.all[1,2]` = 139.17365. Then for the first bar, I need to mark a line corresponding to all the 2s of the rows of `mat.all`. That is `mat.all[2:5,2]`.

Similarly, for the second bar, I need to do this for all the 3s. For the third bar, for all 4s. And for the fourth bar, for the 5 (last one).

Finally, I need to put a text in each bar to show the following percentage decrease based on magnitude of the first value, i.e.,`mat.all[1,2]` = 139.17365.

```
perc.all=round(((mat.all[1,2]-mat.all[1:16,2])*100/mat.all[1,2]),1)
> perc.all
 [1]  0.0  2.1  0.1  2.7 29.6  2.1  4.9  2.8 30.6 29.9 35.2  5.0 31.0 36.1
[15] 36.0 37.0
```

I am adding a png file below that displays how I want my stacked bar plots. I tried to roughly show the first bar.

[image: Sample stacked plot]

I would truly appreciate any help to have my desire output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to do in order to return the plot you have outlined. Also, you haven't provided a detailed example of your desired output but based on the example you gave, hopefully this achieves close to what you want.

There is an issue with the placement one of the labels in this method, and I could not work out the issue so I ended up manually correcting it. If someone can see the error, please comment below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# A dataframe of your matrix
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,rep(2,4),rep(3,6),rep(4,4),5,
                          139.17365,136.27613,139.01464,
                          135.47032,98.02343,136.28064,
                          132.31289,135.26496,96.62991,
                          97.49587,90.17913,132.25711,
                          96.01838,88.87682,89.06218,87.65776),16,2,
                        byrow=F))

colnames(df) <- c("id", "value")

# Get max value of value column
max_value <- max(df[,2])

# Prepare data for plotting
df1 <- df %>%
  # Your "percentage decrease based on magnitude" formula
  mutate(perc_all = round((max(value) - value) * 100 / max(value), 1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  # Assign value for original order (and for barplot labels)
  mutate(ord = paste0("x", 1:n())) %>%
  # Sort data in descending order
  arrange(id, desc(perc_all)) %>%
  # Create vector of barplot labels
  mutate(label_text =  paste0(ord,"=", round(perc_all, 1), "%")) %>%
  # Add one row to each group for absent data
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x,.before = 0)) %>%
  # Add value to new rows so each column adds up to max_value
  mutate(perc_all = ifelse(is.na(perc_all),
                           max_value - sum(perc_all, na.rm = TRUE), perc_all),
         # Add "x" value to new rows
         ord = ifelse(is.na(ord),
                      paste0("x", n()), ord),
         # Calculate label locations for barplot labels
         label_loc = cumsum(lag(perc_all, default = 0))) %>% 
  # Return only the plot data
  filter(id %in% 2:5) %>%
  ungroup()

# Label placement of x3 for id group 3 is incorrect, could not work out why,
# so have to manually edit it
df1[11,6] <- df1[11,6] - 2

# Running this will return a warning, which you can ignore, it just means
# there are NA values in the label_text column
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df1,
           aes(x = id, 
               y = perc_all,
               fill = ord,
               group = ord),
           stat = "identity",
           show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = df1,
            aes(x = id,
                y = label_loc,
                label = label_text),
            vjust = -0.1,
            colour = "black",
            size = 2)
```

[image: result]

***Update based on OP's comment***

You can use the `ggpattern` to create lattice fills. The example below just uses the default patterns. If they do not suit, you will need to explore the documentation for `ggpattern` in order to customise the fills so they appear how you want:

```
library(ggpattern)

ggplot() +
  geom_col_pattern(data = df1,
                   aes(x = id, 
                       y = perc_all,
                       pattern = ord, 
                       pattern_angle = ord, 
                       pattern_spacing = ord),
                   fill = "white",
                   colour = "black",
                   pattern_density = 0.15,
                   pattern_fill    = "grey80",
                   pattern_colour  = "grey40") +
  geom_rect(data = filter(df1, label_loc > 0),
            aes(xmin = id -.18, 
                xmax = id + .18, 
                ymin = label_loc + .1, 
                ymax = label_loc + 1.9), 
            fill = "white",
            alpha = .75) +
  geom_text(data = df1,
            aes(x = id,
                y = label_loc,
                label = label_text),
            vjust = -0.1,
            colour = "black",
            size = 2)
```

[image: result bw]

Comment: Thanks. Although it doesn’t do exactly what I needed, but I can improvise it. Could you please tell me how can I change the color of the bars. Also, is it possible to not use colors and use different types of grids?

Comment: @Dempaty - I have updated my answer to include a solution as per your comment. If this helps you, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick symbol. The rep is appreciated and it also helps others to identify working solutions. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is this what are u trying for

```
mat.all=matrix(c(1,rep(2,4),rep(3,6),rep(4,4),5,139.17365,136.27613,139.01464,135.47032,98.02343,136.28064,132.31289,135.26496,96.62991, 97.49587,90.17913,132.25711,96.01838,88.87682,89.06218,87.65776),16,2,byrow=F)

library(ggplot2)

# Convert the matrix to a data frame
df <- data.frame(mat.all)
perc.all=round(((mat.all[1,2]-mat.all[1:16,2])*100/mat.all[1,2]),1)
# Add a column for percentage decrease
df$perc.decrease <- perc.all


# Plot the stacked bar chart
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(X1), y = X2, fill = factor(X1))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(perc.decrease, "%")),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +  # Optional, format y-axis labels
  labs(title = "Stacked Bar Chart with Percentage Decrease",
       x = "Category",
       y = "Magnitude") +
  theme_minimal()
```